# Не удается открыть источник файла <unistd.h> vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Объясните пожалуйста что необходимо сделать для решения данной проблемы?
Установил VS code, но скомпилировать программу[![Ошибка][1]][1] [![Ошибка библиотеки][2]][2]не могу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h> // ***(Не удается открыть источник файла)***
using namespace std; // Подключаем пространство имен, кол - во строк и столбцов в поле клеток, обозначаем размещение клеток при старте программы.
#define N 40
#define M 20
#define NONE ' ' 
#define Alive '*' 
void initpole(char* P) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N * M; ++i) P[i] = NONE; // Начальное размещение на поле "клеток"
    P[4 * N + 10] = NONE; P[4 * N + 11] = Alive; P[4 * N + 12] = Alive;
    P[5 * N + 10] = Alive; P[5 * N + 11] = Alive; P[5 * N + 12] = NONE;
    P[6 * N + 10] = NONE; P[6 * N + 11] = Alive; P[6 * N + 12] = NONE;
} 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMHqB.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp6Cc.png
```

Comment: В приведенном коде этот заголовочный файл не нужен. Ну и для Visual Studio на Windows его и нет, это заголовочный файл посиксных систем.

Comment: На приложенных картинках видно Visual Studio 2022, а не VS code. `unistd.h` не является частью SDK windows. Если выбрать целевой системой Unix и скачать соответствующее SDK, файл появится.